# Azure Form Recognizer Set API Version

Tags: c#, azure, azure-form-recognizer

I am trying to use the Az Form Recognizer SDK version 4.1.0-beta.1 and the API version "2023_02_28_preview".

The documentation reads that I can use the DocumentAnalysisClient, but it doesnt show how to set the API version to the desired version. Any examples on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot specify the Form recognizer API version in your C# code, Because while using C# SDK for form recognizer, By default it will use the Form Recognizer REST API version **3.0** or use 4.1.0-beta.1 by default depending on the Nuget package version you have imported.

> Refer the Note which states Important in this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/how-to-guides/use-sdk-rest-api?view=form-recog-3.0.0&pivots=programming-language-csharp&tabs=windows)
> **Important
>
> This project targets Form Recognizer REST API version
>
> **3.0**** and Refer the Note below from this [**link.**](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/dotnet/Azure.AI.FormRecognizer/4.0.0/index.html)
> **Note: This version of the client library defaults to the `2022-08-31` version of the service.**

***You can select your required API version while importing the Form Recognizer Nuget package in Visual Studio like below:-***

[image]

**After importing the above **Azure.AI.FormRecognizer** Nuget package with desired API version you do not need to specifically mention it again in your code.**

Now, you can refer the code from this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/how-to-guides/use-sdk-rest-api?view=form-recog-3.0.0&pivots=programming-language-csharp&tabs=windows) and run the sample code to manage form recognizer resource.

> Note:- above document uses API version 4.0.0 as mentioned - Select version **4.0.0** from the dropdown menu and install the package in your project.

**Code:-**

> ```cs
> using Azure; using Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.DocumentAnalysis;
>
> //use your `key` and `endpoint` environment variables to create your
> `AzureKeyCredential` and `DocumentAnalysisClient` instances string key
> = "<api-key>"; string endpoint = "https://siliconformrecgnizer123.cognitiveservices.azure.com/";
> AzureKeyCredential credential = new AzureKeyCredential(key);
> DocumentAnalysisClient client = new DocumentAnalysisClient(new
> Uri(endpoint), credential);
>
> //sample document Uri fileUri = new
> Uri("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-REST-api-samples/master/curl/form-recognizer/rest-api/read.png");
>
> AnalyzeDocumentOperation operation = await
> client.AnalyzeDocumentFromUriAsync(WaitUntil.Completed,
> "prebuilt-read", fileUri); AnalyzeResult result = operation.Value;
>
> foreach (DocumentPage page in result.Pages) {
>     Console.WriteLine($"Document Page {page.PageNumber} has {page.Lines.Count} line(s), {page.Words.Count} word(s),");
>     Console.WriteLine($"and {page.SelectionMarks.Count} selection mark(s).");
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < page.Lines.Count; i++)
>     {
>         DocumentLine line = page.Lines[i];
>         Console.WriteLine($"  Line {i} has content: '{line.Content}'.");
>
>         Console.WriteLine($"    Its bounding polygon (points ordered clockwise):");
>
>         for (int j = 0; j < line.BoundingPolygon.Count; j++)
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine($"      Point {j} => X: {line.BoundingPolygon[j].X}, Y: {line.BoundingPolygon[j].Y}");
>         }
>     } }
>
> foreach (DocumentStyle style in result.Styles) {
>     // Check the style and style confidence to see if text is handwritten.
>     // Note that value '0.8' is used as an example.
>
>     bool isHandwritten = style.IsHandwritten.HasValue && style.IsHandwritten == true;
>
>     if (isHandwritten && style.Confidence > 0.8)
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine($"Handwritten content found:");
>
>         foreach (DocumentSpan span in style.Spans)
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine($"  Content: {result.Content.Substring(span.Index, span.Length)}");
>         }
>     } }
>
> Console.WriteLine("Detected languages:");
>
> foreach (DocumentLanguage language in result.Languages) {
>     Console.WriteLine($"  Found language with locale'{language.Locale}' with confidence {language.Confidence}."); }
> ```

**Output:-**

[image]

Alternatively, You can directly call the API by going to this [link](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-2023-02-28-preview/operations/AnalyzeDocument) or this link and passing the require parameters like below:-

> [image]
>
> [image]

> Note- Form Recognizer 2023-02-28-preview is still in preview and not Generally available so some features might not yet work completely.

***You can also Specify API version in Form recognizer studio while creating your model like below:-***

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation about specifying version numbers.

I am trying to figure out how to send PDF data to the Analyze API from the API link you sent above. Any examples?\